# jquery .post not response

Tags: php, jquery

I am posting an attribute id to a php file, and I'm not getting a response.

jquery code :

```
$("#droppable").on("drop", function (event, ui) {
        var rel_value = $(ui.draggable).attr("id");
        var id_worker = rel_value.split("_");
        $.post('http://example.com/mohdrag/test.php', { "id_worker": id_worker[1]}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#worker_box').html(data);

    })
```

and test.php code :

```
<?php
$field1 = $_POST['id_worker'];
        if (!isset($field1) || empty($field1)){
            echo "empty";
        }
        elseif($field1=10){
        echo "hello";
        }
?>
```

I am not getting a response.

I expect to see "hello" and show it in #worker_box

My code : [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/UyAHICe/1/edit)

full code is [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/UyAHICe/1/edit)

I think the problem is with my php code.

**UPDATE:**

and also console error is :

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

Sorry for my poor English

Comment: No errors in your console?

Comment: @putvande firebug console dont show any errors just url is red

Comment: OK. Sounds like you are not allowed to do that. What statuscode is it giving you?

Comment: @putvande i upload html file to server and work now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your elseif condition, you have used a single equals sign. To compare variables, you need double or triple equals. Single equals means assign, so your code won't work.

Try double equals and put the 10 in quotes, as the post will be a string.

Comment: i change php code to : <?php
$field1 = $_POST['id_worker'];
  if($field1=='10'){
  echo "salam";
  }
?> and not work too

Comment: Thanks that is work , excuse me i upload my html file to server and work but  i can not post from local thanks

Comment: You are unable to post from a localhost to a live domain, probably because of CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing). If you want to enable that, you can do so by following the information found here http://enable-cors.org/ But, you should only do so if you want to allow posting from anywhere. Normally, you would only want to allow posting from the same domain for security reasons.